# BoringSSL crash while launching

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

quick question. I'm trying to install CometChatPro SDK on my app and after doing that after launch i get an error on this line:

```
  sdallocx(ptr, size + OPENSSL_MALLOC_PREFIX, 0 /* flags */);
```

The Error:

```
Thread 14: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x106c62be0)
```

This error refers to BoringSSL -> src -> Crypto -> mem file Line 129
I did try to remove all the changes i have made, i only left the installed pod, but the error seems to persist. I'm getting the error after Application finishes launching.

My App file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import UIKit

@main
struct Darbo_ManijaApp: App {
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

var body: some Scene {
    
    let viewModel = AppViewModel()
    let userdataManager = UserDataManager()
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
            .environmentObject(userdataManager)
    }
}
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or how to find the cause of the crash?
Thanks in advance!